# Convert Xml containing both schema and data into java object using Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have tried Jackson API to parse below XML into java object but it did not work. I only want object that represents the student record . Can anybody help me with this? For standard xml format, the Jackson API works but for the below example I am not able to do so

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataTable xmlns="http://*****.com">
    <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="StudentRecord" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="StudentRecord">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="StudentId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element name="FName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element name="LName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element name="Address1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
        <DocumentElement xmlns="">
            <StudentRecord diffgr:id="StudentRecord1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                <StudentId>&&&&&&&</StudentId>
                <FName>ABC</FName>
                <LName>DSF</LName>
                <Address1>12345</Address1>
            </StudentRecord>
        </DocumentElement>
    </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataTable>
```

Answer (score 3):

SimpleXml can do it, first 1 POJO:

```
public class StudentRecord {
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlName("diffgr:id")
    public String id;
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlName("msdata:rowOrder")
    public int rowOrder;
    @XmlName("StudentId")
    public String studentId;
    @XmlName("FName")
    public String firstName;
    @XmlName("LName")
    public String lastName;
    @XmlName("Address1")
    public String address1;
}
```

Next we turn the XML into a DOM, then we grab the element we need and convert that element to our class.

```
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final Element root = simple.fromXml(xml);
final StudentRecord student = simple.fromXml(root.children.get(1).children.get(0).children.get(0), StudentRecord.class);
System.out.println(student.id + " : " + student.firstName + " " + student.lastName);
```

This code will print:

```
StudentRecord1 : ABC DSF
```

SimpleXml is in maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But I did not like the idea of doing indexing to access element. can't we set root to StudentRecord directly? @jurgen

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is some sort of XPath query on the raw XML to select a particular node and then start the serialization process from there. But no such functionality exists yet. Right now the best you can do is to hide away the ugliness in a function.